# Not able to delete topics from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Even after enabling **delete.topic.enable=true** in *server.config*,
deletion of topics is not working. I am getting the following error on recreating the topic again:

```
Topic 'test' already exists.
[2017-05-23 06:47:05,757] ERROR
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'test' already exists.
```

Comment: Did you restart your Kafka broker in order to enable the parameter and then use this command : `bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper HOST:2181 --delete --topic TOPIC`

Comment: yes , i did restart the brokers

Comment: And what message did you get when you use the deleting command ?

Answer (score 9):

You can not delete a topic when consuming it. Use `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` or simple `ps -aux|grep Consumer` to find any possible consumers which block the operation.

Answer (score 4):

Remove meta data in Zookeeper:

```
./bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181
rmr /brokers/topics/mytopic
rmr /admin/delete_topics/mytopic
```

Comment: `rmr` has been replaced with `deleteall`, for reference for future readers

Answer (score 1):

If you use the latest Kafka (v. ~0.10.) then after you enabled the `delete.topic.enable=true` option you have to:

1. Restart Kafka
2. Delete topic:

   ```
   kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic mytopic --delete
   ```
3. Check that it was marked for deletion:

   ```
   kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
   mytopic - marked for deletion
   ```
4. And wait a bit.

And if you use some old version of Kafka, then try to delete the topic from a zookeeper-shell.

Comment: This won't work if Kafka & Zookeeper are running in different instances

Answer (score 1):

If the zookeeper is a standalone instance (not on the localhost), mark for deletion of topics won't delete it properly.

One suggestion would be to use [Zookeeper Exhibitor](https://github.com/soabase/exhibitor) & delete it from admin & brokers.

Exhibitor give a UI interface to visualise how the topics & kafka brokers are arranged.

Comment: yes , zookeepers are not on localhost, they are standalone instances

Comment: @chetandev yeah, then you could it with Exhibitor, it works.